# Iterator in Thread On CopyOnWriteArrayList not working

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, iterator, copyonwritearraylist

I am doing some exercises for the OCP exam. At the moment I tried to **print out** the **contents** of a [**CopyOnWriteArrayList**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) when using **several threads**. According to the documentation the iterator of a CopyOnWriteArrayList will

> print the numbers in the list which are present at the moment the iterator is created

So when starting **one thread writing** on the CopyOnWriteArrayList and **another one reading** from the CopyOnWriteArrayList I expect (sometimes) some items printed out. When traversing the CopyOnWriteArrayList **after** the writing thread finished I expect a *new iterator* printing out **all of the items**.

Unfortunately this **does not work** when using **anonymous implementations of Runnable interface**. But it works when using custom thread classes, in which I pass a reference to CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Right now, I cannot see why this happens. I am not sure if `final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> intList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();` causes this effect - and if it is so - I have no clue why at all?

Any input on this topic would be appreciated!

**Using anonymous implementations of Runnable - does not work as expected**

```
static void copyOnWriteCollections() {
    System.out.println("copyOnWriteCollections".toUpperCase());

    final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> intList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    Thread tADD = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                intList.add(i);
            }
        }
    });
    tADD.start();

    /// will print the numbers in the list which are present
    /// at the moment the iterator is created
    Thread tREAD = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Integer i : intList) {
                System.out.print(i);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    });     
    tREAD.start();

    try {
        tADD.join();
        tREAD.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // will print out all numbers - as iterator is created when all
    // modifications
    // to intList have finished
    System.out.println();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("new");
            System.out.println("\tsize of intList: " + intList.size());

            Iterator<Integer> it = intList.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int i = it.next();
                System.out.print(i);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println("end");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**output (sometimes - as there are threads)**
[image: first read thread prints out some numbers, second read thread won't print out any numbers!]

**use of custom thread class - works as expected**

```
class CopyOnWriteThread extends Thread {

    Iterator<Integer> it = null;
    boolean read = false;
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> intList = null;

    public CopyOnWriteThread(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> intList, boolean read) {
        this.intList = intList;
        this.read = read;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (read) {
            it = intList.iterator();

            System.out.println("START read (" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
            System.out.print("\t");
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(it.next());
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("END read (" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
        } else {
            System.out.println("START write (" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                intList.add(i);
            }
            System.out.println("END write (" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")");
        }
    }
}

static void copyOnWriteCollections_CustomThread() {
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> intList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    CopyOnWriteThread tWRITE = new CopyOnWriteThread(intList, false);
    CopyOnWriteThread tREAD = new CopyOnWriteThread(intList, true);
    tWRITE.start();
    tREAD.start();

    try {
        tWRITE.join();
        tREAD.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    CopyOnWriteThread tREAD2 = new CopyOnWriteThread(intList, true);
    tREAD2.start();
}
```

**output - works as expected**
[image: first read thread prints out some numbers, second read thread prints out all numbers]

Currently I am working on a **Win10 machine, with JDK 1.7.0_25 and Eclipse Mars Release 4.5.0**

Comment: You're not comparing apples to apples - In your first example, tREAD starts immediately after tWRITE, and in the second example there's a 5ms delay before tREAD is started. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to test or figure out here..

Comment: @DarthAndroid: It looks to me like the issue in question is that the second reader thread in the first example doesn't print any elements, despite the fact that the writer thread's completion *happens-before* the second reader starts and despite the fact that the second reader sees an `intList.size()` of 10000. I agree that the `sleep` in the second example is weird, though.

Comment: Incidentally, a [quick test](http://ideone.com/pcmBbZ) on Ideone doesn't show the effect in the question.

Comment: @DarthAndroid ty for the reminder - I'll cut the delay out. Although this does not change anything on my computer. sleep(5) was just for testing purposes

Comment: @user2357112 ty for the reminder - just removed sleep(5) - was for testing purposes only. and yes - you got me right. Concerning your quick test - I can see the (correct result) on Ideone too. Unfortunatelly on my win10 machine - the strange behaviour still remains .. (i'll edit question and put in jdk version too)

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer Franz, I just tried to run the first version of your code and it works as expected - prints all numbers in second run... are you sure you have added the exact sources?

Comment: @nukie - i've just added an *answer* to this topic. If you have any more comments/input I'd be glad to here them! thx in advance for your effort

Answer (score 0):

As @user2357112 posted there is nothing wrong with the code. The problem seems to be **Eclipse related**!

When running the question code in Eclipse Mars / JRE 1.7.0_25 it won't print out numbers from 0 to 9999. Instead it will exit right away as if *there was no new iterator*.

I compiled the code from command line and started it by using `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`. Both showed correct output.

**java command**

```
java -classpath "c:\Chapter14\ConcurrentCollections\bin" concurrentCollections.TestClass
```

**result**

[image: Command line output - relevant pieces]

**javaw command**

```
javaw -classpath "c:\Chapter14\ConcurrentCollections\bin" concurrentCollections.TestClass > "c:\test.txt"
```

**result**

[image: test file contents - first xxx numbers - contains all numbers]

Right now I can say (for sure) there is nothing wrong with my code, nor with the JVM!

**EDIT**

I redirected the output to a file by modifying *Run Configurations*. Restarted the application in eclipse. `Output.txt` contains all numbers - but in my console window within Eclipse (*allocate console*) the numbers won't appear...

[image: Run Configurations Eclipse]

Comment: whoa! how can it be? mb you forgot to build sources after latest code modifications? ))

Comment: I double checked my code, built it several times. So, no - I did not forget to build the sources. It seems as the problems is *specific* to eclipse and to the *allocated console output window*.